Reverse proxifying Logic App HTTP endpoint
We implemented Logic App deployment on consumption Plan (no Azure Service Plan) that has HTTP input.
As we push it via API, it deploys well and returns endpoint HTTP URL (such as https[://]prod-1.francecentral.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/deadbeefdeadbeefb01324dd6a21d67c/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=xxxxx).
We then proxify this address into an nginx RVP pretty URL and it works well.
Yet each time I redeploy (remove/re-add) Logic App, there is a new Endpoint, so it breaks RVP. The associated Logic app still has same name/location.
Isn't there an Azure hack or service (even nonfree) to follow URL renewals?
Thanks,
Solution
Adding APIManager allows to add Logic app object directly in reverse proxification !

static addresses are described in the reverse proxy. Just don't describe the entire address
